# length of polar curve.

Tags: calculus

Find the length of the polar curve;

$$r=e^{a\theta}, -\pi \le \theta \le \pi$$

any help on how I can simplify and calculate this? im getting very confused cuz of the a?

Comment: Where exactly are you having trouble? This seems to have come up in a class or test you are using; You have probably seen a formula/guide for the computation. If the abstraction of a generic $a$ is confusing you, you might first try using numbers $5$ or $7$, for example.

Comment: google your title and read e.g. http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PolarArcLength.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in polar coordinates the infinitesimal arc length $ds$ is given by $$ds \sqrt{(dr)^2  +r^2(d\, \theta)^2} = \sqrt{\alpha^2 e^{2\alpha \theta}+e^{2\alpha \theta}}\, d\theta $$ so 
$$s = \sqrt{\alpha^2 +1}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{\alpha \theta} d\theta = \frac{\sqrt{\alpha^2 +1}}{\alpha}\left(e^{\pi\alpha} - e^{-\pi\alpha}\right)  $$

Comment: @yeyy123, i made a mistake. corrected now.